# Install a corporate proxy for Dropbox to reduce network bandwidth

Tags: proxy, dropbox

One of our IT people was working on a Dropbox proxy before he left, but he gave no information about what he was doing.

What we want to do is have some sort of proxy on our server that allows users on the network to download Dropbox files from the proxy instead of the cloud.  We're trying to fix a problem where one person will upload a file through Dropbox, and then everyone else in the network slams the router trying to download that file from Dropbox at the same time.

Would a peer-to-peer solution (like AeroFS, I believe) work better in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dropbox LAN Sync is what you want to enable.

Quoting from https://www.dropbox.com/help/137/en

> LAN sync is a Dropbox feature that speeds syncing dramatically when
>   the file exists on your Local Area Network (LAN).
>
> What does that mean exactly? Well, when you add a file to your
>   computer's Dropbox, the file is then synced with Dropbox servers.
>   Dropbox will then initiate the syncing process as soon as it
>   determines a change has been made to the file. All linked computers
>   and shared folders will then download any new version of the file.
>   With LAN syncing, Dropbox will look for the new file on your Local
>   Area Network first, bypassing the need to download the file from
>   Dropbox servers, thus speeding up the syncing process considerably.
>
> LAN sync is an extra advantage for use in locations where computers
>   are networked together over the same router or other local area
>   network.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried owncloud? dropbox clone, can be hosted at your company, as far is proxy, not sure how good your linux skills are, squid can help! but I would recommend owncloud, I think it will be a good fit.